# Assigning raster values to spatial point using R?

Tags: raster, r, overlay

I have a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` and create a `raster` object. I assign each raster cell a value and like to extract that value for each spatial point. I.e. if a point lies within a raster, I'd like to end up with that raster cell number in a new column in my `SpatialPointsDataFrame`.

This is how I proceed:

```
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
```

I define a `crs` and this might be the problem (?).

```
crs <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
```

I've uploaded a subset of my `SpatialPointsDataFrame` [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1shnu1oht3fv6tm/pointsdf.Rds?dl=0). To illustrate my problem I need a shapefile of South Africa:

```
za.spdf <- readRDS("pointsdf.Rds")

## Shapefile of south africa
za <- getData('GADM', country='ZAF', level=0)
za <- spTransform(za, crs)
```

In order to inspect, see this plot, everything seems fine:

```
plot(za)
plot(za.spdf, add=T, col="red", pch=20, cex=2)
```

[image]

I then create my raster object and assign values to it:

```
## Raster over south africa (100x100km)
r <- raster(extent(za))
res(r) <- c(100000, 100000)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
proj4string(r) <- crs
```

I thought I could just transform the raster object into a shapefile and use `over`. However, this returns only `NA` values...

```
grid100 <- rasterToPolygons(r, n = 4, na.rm = TRUE)
spatial100 <- sp::over(za.spdf, grid100)
spatial100
          layer
 14777    NA
 14785    NA
 14793    NA
 14796    NA
 14800    NA
```

When plotting, the rastering and the map overlay nicely. However, where are my points?

```
plot(grid100)
plot(za, add=T)
plot(za.spdf, add=T, col="red", pch=20, cex=2)
```

[image]

I couldn't figure out what the problem is. I highly suspect that my `SpatialPointsDataFrame` does not correspond with the map and therefore with the raster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the points aren't the correct CRS, seems to be lat/long coordinates, not meter coordinates. Also, *I assign each raster cell a value and like to extract that value for each spatial point*: Use `extract()` for this, instead of converting raster to polygons (a very slow process):

```
za.spdf <- readRDS('pointsdf.Rds')

za <- getData('GADM', country='ZAF', level=0)
crs(za.spdf) <- crs(za)

crs <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=20 +lat_2=-23 +lat_0=0 +lon_0=25 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"

za <- spTransform(za, crs)
za.spdf <- spTransform(za.spdf, crs)

r <- raster(extent(za))
res(r) <- c(100000, 100000)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
crs(r) <- crs(za)

extract(r,za.spdf)
## [1] 207 207 210 211 207
```